# Get hashes of commit that are behind/ahead remote branch in git

Tags: git

It usually happens that local branch is behind/ahead remote branch and git reports about it:

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

However, is there any simple way of knowning with *exact* commits are these? I mean, the 3 commit hashes that are ahead origin in the above example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but I'd do `git log --oneline origin/develop..develop`. This should output something like

```
1234abc Commit message
abcd123 Some other commit message
1a2b3c4 And yet another message
```

`origin/develop..develop` means "all commits in the `develop` branch that aren't in the `origin/develop` branch". Think of it like "differences starting from the first branch and going to the second branch".

If you're behind, you can do the opposite: `git log --oneline develop..origin/develop`.

And if you really only want the hashes, instead of `--oneline` you can use something like `--pretty="%h"`. This will output something like

```
1234abc
abcd123
1a2b3c4
```

You can learn more about `^`, `..` and `...` in revisions from [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#_description):

> You can think of this as a set operation. Commits given on the command
>   line form a set of commits that are reachable from any of them, and
>   then commits reachable from any of the ones given with `^` in front are
>   subtracted from that set. The remaining commits are what comes out in
>   the command’s output. Various other options and paths parameters can
>   be used to further limit the result.
>
> Thus, the following command:
>
> ```
> $ git rev-list foo bar ^baz
> ```
>
> means "list all the commits which are
>   reachable from `foo` or `bar`, but not from `baz`".
>
> A special notation `<commit1>..<commit2>` can be used as a short-hand
>   for `^'<commit1>' <commit2>`. For example, either of the following may
>   be used interchangeably:
>
> ```
> $ git rev-list origin..HEAD
> $ git rev-list HEAD ^origin
> ```

Comment: You mention `...` but I'll add in a comment that this is the specifier that gets you both sets, i.e., it gets r1..r2 and r2..r1 combined.  The one drawback is that it's not obvious which ones are from the first group, and which ones are from the second.